# Linking SQL Server database to ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, arcgis-online, sql-server

I'm not sure this is possible, and the ESRI documentation is a bit of a mess it seems. Or maybe it's not possible at all and the ESRI documentation is giving me the nearest it can.

Basically, the organisation I work for has a fair bit of data on an SQL Server - both spatial and non-spatial.

We want to link this to ArcGIS Online / Collector, so that a user can log in and see the latest data and have it updated. Bonus points if they can make updates back.

I believe this will require ArcGIS Server, and there seem to be a whole myriad of options. I've been told that it doesn't, but not sure whether to believe it. Also, we'll be trialing ArcGIS Server shortly, in order to make our SQL Server database into a geodatabase (this is the approach ESRI themselves have said to use).

If we do that, even once the trial expires, would we be able to have ArcGIS Online look at that?

As near as I can understand it, we need to set up an ArcGIS Server web service.

Would we still be able to use this once the trial expires?

We've currently got a standard editor licence.

Comment: By using server you're providing an alternate to ArcGIS Online as a web service from your own server. Editing data from the field, that *should* be possible but you would need the Advanced Enterprise to do this (the *really* expensive one). Note that the number of collector licenses that are 'free' with your ArcGIS Server are limited. I hope that you have an Esri representative to set this up for you.. listen closely to what they say & take notes; setting up server is a non-trivial task. When your trial expires your web service will stop working but will remain in-situ ready to be licensed.

Comment: It gets expensive but can be done via ArcGIS Server (Advanced) as Michael mentions.